# Can we use paypal or amzon checkout in iPhone Apps distributed using in house distribution?

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

In case of Enterprise distribution, can we use our own payment integration like paypal or amazon checkout (excluding in-app purchase). And is there any specific criteria we need to meet in order to be able to go for in house distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to integrate your own payment methods. And since in-house apps don't have to pass Apples review process, Apple won't mind because they won't notice.

Note however that in-house distribution is only allowed among employees of the company enrolled in the Enterprise Developer Program. While this is of course your business, I can't think of a good reason to charge your employees for services within your companies own app. Just in case you intend to distribute the app in question to persons who are not affiliated with your company you should be aware that, should apple learn about what you're doing, they are likely to shut your account down. Which would immediately switch your app off, too.

Comment: Great info. Is this true  that each user who is going to use the App need to pay $299?

Comment: No - the company or organization enrolled in the program has to pay a yearly fee of $299, but distribution of the app itself is not technically limited or charged for separately. You're required to implement means to ensure that the app is used by your employees only, though. Additionally, you'll have to re-distribute the app at least once per year, since the enterprise distribution certificate will expire after one year, like the certs for the standard programs do, too. So you'll need to build and distribute the app again once you renewed the certificate.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Is there any way apple follows to check if a user not part of the company using the App?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. Since enterprise distributed apps **do** in fact contact apple servers (to check if the certificate with which they have been signed is still valid), it may be possible, technically, to create some sort of distribution chart. If it turns out the app is spread all over the world, with not even a few installations in close proximity to each other, it is pretty safe to assume it is not used by employees only. Whether they sneak after enterprises like that I don't know. But the main risk I think is that someone just might tell them anyway.

Comment: Thanks Toaster. And the "enterprise distributed apps contacting the apple server" comes where? I am not going to build logic in to my App. Then how come this happens?

Comment: This is built into iOS, I assume. Along with the app comes a provisioning profile which identifies the app as being enterprise distributed. It probably is within iOS' responsibility to check if the profile has been signed with a valid certificate before allowing such an app to run.

Answer (score 0):

Why is there a need to redistribute the app, the cert should simple be renewed, right?  I mean the standard program certs expire every year but only a renewal is required, not a redistribution.  Why is there a difference?

Comment: because app store distributed apps get re-signed with some Appstore specific Apple-certificate which doesn't expire. Enterprise distributed apps on the other hand don't go into the store and hence don't receive that special treatment. Instead, they rely on the enterprise distribution cert and regularly check if it's still valid on startup. Which means they stop working once the certificate expires or gets revoked. A renewed certificate is **not** the same certificate as before - you absolutely need to sign your apps again using the new one.

Comment: Thanks, I meant to add a comment.